# Jquery Removing multiple classes

Tags: jquery

I have an several buttons on my site which require for the user to toggle class from active to inActive. I have four buttons therefore when the user click on button one the classes for the other buttons need to be disabled.

i've read several posts on this subject apparently the way to solve this problem is `.removeClass('btnOne', 'btnTwo')` etc?

I have tried this and does work ? Below is how my code is structured, i have removed the `removeClass` property for the time being until i get it right..

```
            $('#search-btn').click(function(){
                $('.nav-bar-wrap').toggleClass('searchActive');
            });

            $('.more-btn').click(function(){
                $('.more-menu').toggleClass('moreMenuActive');
            });

            $('.ac-btn').click(function(){
                $('.account-menu').toggleClass('acMenuActive')
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't comma-separate them as two different arguments. You only need to separate them with spaces within one string:

```
elem.removeClass('btnOne btnTwo')
```

From [jQuery's `removeClass` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

> #### `.removeClass( [className ] )`
>
> **className**
> Type: String
> One or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.

Comment: $('.nav-bar-wrap').toggleClass('searchActive').removeClass(['moreMenuActive acMenuActive']); <— like this?

Comment: @NewBoy no. Remove the square brackets.

Comment: can you write it out based of my code it's not working for me, i think i'm being stupid.